# Reactjs best strategy to define a variable for render method

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, reactjs

Lets suppose I have this chunk of code, which define the component `@authComponent` depending on some conditions:

```
@AuthPanel = React.createClass
  componentWillReceiveProps: ->
    @authComponent =  if @props.uiState.auth_panel?.signed_in
                        <SignOutForm uiState={@props.uiState} socket={@props.socket} />
                      else
                        <SignInForm uiState={@props.uiState} socket={@props.socket} />

  render: ->
    <div className="navbar-collapse">
      {@authComponent}
    </div>
```

The main trouble which I faced is the difficulty to understand where should I define my `@authComponent` variable.

Here's the list of my ideas:

- I've tried it with `componentWillMount` first, but I've met the trouble - `@authComponent` invoked just one time.
- If I try `componentWillReceiveProps`, I'll get rendering at all times except first.
- I can try to define the function
- I can define `@authComponent` exactly on `render` method, but it seems dirty.
- I can use construction like that: `{div || <SignInForm />}`, but it not sexy too

Is there any appropriate and right way for defining my component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is better, in my opinion:

```
@AuthPanel = React.createClass
  getAuthComponent: ->
    if @props.uiState.auth_panel?.signed_in
      return <SignOutForm uiState={@props.uiState} socket={@props.socket} />
    else
      return <SignInForm uiState={@props.uiState} socket={@props.socket} />
  render: ->
    <div className="navbar-collapse">
      {@authComponent()}
    </div>
```

I've found it there: https://github.com/planningcenter/react-patterns#sub-render

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing bad and dirty in putting your `@authComponent` inside `render()` method. I've seen a lot of examples on GitHub which use the same approach. Creation of the component doesn't make a big difference to the performance in you case I think because React will modify DOM only when it finds some change in the component tree.

Comment: ok, thanks! Please let me know, if you'll find better approach sometimes

Comment: Please review another solution, which is working for me